# How to compute dot product with negative samples

Tags: cntk

CNTK currently provides function to perform Cosine distance with negative samples. I am wondering how one could possibly do a simple dot product with negative sampling in CNTK.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `query` is the thing you want to match up against `candidates` and normalize across all candidates in the batch, you can use something like this:

```
def all_pairs_loss(query, candidates):
    qry_matrix = C.unpack_batch(query)
    cnd_matrix = C.unpack_batch(candidates)
    all_inner_products = C.to_batch(C.times_transpose(cnd_matrix, qry_matrix))

    positive_inner_products = C.reduce_sum(qry * candidates, axis=0)
    loss = C.reduce_log_sum_exp(all_inner_products) - positive_inner_products
    return loss
```